# Scale down Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes

I am using

`kubectl scale --replicas=0 -f deployment.yaml`

to stop all my running pods. Please let me know if there are better ways to bring down all running pods to Zero keeping configuration, deployments etc.. intact, so that I can scale up later as required.

Comment: Are you experiencing that `scale` is behaving different from what you would expect, or are you merely confirming that using scale in that way is a best practice _(which it is, AFAIK)_?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You are doing the correct action; *traditionally* the `scale` verb is applied just to the resource name, as in `kubectl scale deploy my-awesome-deployment --replicas=0`, which removes the need to always point at the *specific file* that describes that deployment, but there's nothing wrong (that I know of) with using the file if that is more convenient for you.

Comment: I did this for all of my deployments. So I have watched `kubectl get pods` output and saw how all pods were terminated. Now it tells `No resources found.`. As I can see I still have two running nodes with `kubectl get nodes`. If I do `docker ps` inside them, there are only Kuberenetes built-in containers running. How to terminate all nodes (AWS EKS)?

Answer (score 89):

The solution is pretty easy and straightforward

```
kubectl scale deploy -n <namespace> --replicas=0 --all
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does `--all` do in this context? For some reason it only worked with this flag for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me, returns `error: no objects passed to scale`

Comment: `--all` applies the scale to all deployments (in the namespace).  You could replace it by the name of one specific deployment.

Comment: @insideClaw that happened to me as well, then I remembered that i have no deployments, just jobs.

Comment: --all was suggested only because the person wants to scale down all pods (literally to 0). One can place whatever namespace he/she wants through -n <namespace_name>

Comment: If you have "error: no objects passed to scale" error make sure your kube context is valid. Especially whether it points to existing namespace.

Answer (score 28):

Here we go.
Scales down all deployments in a whole namespace:

```
kubectl get deploy -n <namespace> -o name | xargs -I % kubectl scale % --replicas=0 -n <namespace>
```

To scale up set `--replicas=1` (or any other required number)  accordingly

Comment: Why not just use `kubectl scale deploy -n <namespace> --replicas=0 --all`?

Comment: Cool, didn't know. Though we use another grep between those pipes in my construction to filter deployments that are required to stop.
kubectl get deploy -n <namespace> -o name | grep backend | xargs -I % kubectl scale % --replicas=0 -n <namespace>

Comment: This command may be useful if you need some filters by label for example
`kubectl get deploy -n <namespace> -o name -l app.kubernetes.io/component=consumer | xargs -I % kubectl scale % --replicas=0 -n <namespace>`

Comment: The short command does not work with older versions of kubectl, this one worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: why `-I` and `%`?

Answer (score 19):

Use the following to scale down/up all deployments and stateful sets in the current namespace. Useful in development when switching projects.

```sh
kubectl scale statefulset,deployment --all --replicas=0
```

Add a namespace flag if needed

```sh
kubectl scale statefulset,deployment -n mynamespace --all --replicas=0
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  kubectl get deployments
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
app-gke   3/3     3            3           13m

  kubectl scale deploy app-gke --replicas=5
deployment.extensions/app-gke scaled


kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
app-gke-7b768cd6d7-b25px   2/2     Running             0          11m
app-gke-7b768cd6d7-glj5v   0/2     ContainerCreating   0          4s
app-gke-7b768cd6d7-jdt6l   2/2     Running             0          11m
app-gke-7b768cd6d7-ktx87   2/2     Running             0          11m
app-gke-7b768cd6d7-qxpgl   0/2     ContainerCreating   0          4s
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can scale multiple resources as given below:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/app deployment/database
```

And You can scale ALL resource as given below:

```
kubectl scale --all --replicas=0 --namespace=default deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want generic patch:

```
namespace=devops-ci-dev
kubectl get deployment -n ${namespace} --no-headers| awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I elhay kubectl patch deployment -n ${namespace} -p '{"spec": {"replicas": 1}}' elhay
```

Change `namespace=devops-ci-dev`, to be your name space.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more granularity with pipes or grep, here is another shell solution:

```
for i in $(kubectl get deployments | grep -v NAME | grep -v app | awk '{print $1}'); do kubectl scale --replicas=2 deploy $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non command way, if you are using k9s interface.

- Go to deployments, select the deployment you want to scale up or down.
- Press s from keyboard, this is a shortcut to Scale a deployment.
- Edit the number of replicas in popup.

Answer (score -2):

`kubectl get svc | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl scale deploy --replicas=0`